# UISplitViewController transition from top to bottom instead of right to left

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a root UISplitViewController that contains a UINavigationController related with a DetailViewController. The DetailViewController calls, via a storyboard push segue, another ViewController, called SecondViewController. When the user clicks on the Back button in SecondViewController toolbar, all the UISplitViewController has a transition from top to bottom, instead of a right-to-left transition of the DetailViewController. In the xCode designed all the transition style properties are set as "Flip horizontal". Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm getting a similar problem but when pressing back on the MasterView. I only happens on iOS 5.0. It's fine on 5.1 and 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem in ios 5, landscape orientation. 
Adding shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: both in Master & Detail controller solved problem

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```